# Is it beneficial to boost the transmit power from a transmitter past 2W around 2.4GHz?

Tags: electronics, transmitter, amplifier, microwave

I have a ready-made transmitter that outputs 2W of RF power at 2.4GHz carrier frequency (I'm trying to transmit TV using DVB-S2) into the antenna, and I was wondering if it made sense to add a power amp between the transmitter and the antenna to improve the reception. I could not find low noise amplifiers which had a sufficiently high saturation power, so I wonder if regular power amps wouldn't degrade the signal roughly as much as they boost the overall power.

What's your take as connoisseurs?

Comment: What kind of signal are you trying to boost?  Wi-Fi?  (Please [edit your question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/18833/edit) to answer, rather than answering in a comment.)

Comment: DVB-S2, I've updated my question

Comment: Increasing the power will increase the received signal level and increase the range. Are you licenced to do that in the portion of the 2.4GHz band you are working in. You will need to either design or purchase amps designed for that band, they are all different.